# How to troubleshoot package loading error in spark

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, azure-eventhub

I'm using spark in HDInsight with Jupyter notebook. I'm using the %%configure "magic" to import packages. Every time there is a problem with the package, spark crashes with the error:

> The code failed because of a fatal error:     Status 'shutting_down' not
>   supported by session..

or

> The code failed because of a fatal error:     Session 28 unexpectedly
>   reached final status 'dead'. See logs:

Usually the problem was with me mistyping the name of the package, so after a few attempts I could solve it. Now I'm trying to import spark-streaming-eventhubs_2.11 and I think I got the name right, but I still receive the error. I looked at all kinds of logs but still couldn't find the one which shows any relevant info. Any idea how to troubleshoot similar errors?

```
%%configure -f
{ "conf": {"spark.jars.packages": "com.microsoft.azure:spark-streaming-eventhubs_2.11:2.0.5" }}
```

Additional info: when I run

```
spark-shell --conf spark.jars.packages=com.microsoft.azure:spark-streaming-eventhubs_2.11:2.0.5
```

The shell starts fine, and downloads the package

Answer (score 2):

I finally was able to find the log files which contain the error. There are two log files which could be interesting

- Livy log: livy-livy-server.out
- Yarn log

On my HDInsight cluster, I found the livy log by connecting to one of the Head nodes with SSH and downloading a a file at this path (this log didn't contain useful info):

> /var/log/livy/livy-livy-server.out

The actual error was in the yarn log file accessible from YarnUI. In HDInsight Azure Portal, go to "Cluster dashboard" -> "Yarn", find your session (KILLED status), click on "Logs" in the table, find "Log Type: stderr", click "click here for full log".

The problem in my case was Scala version incompatibility between one of the dependencies of spark-streaming_2.11 and Livy. This is supposed to be fixed Livy 0.4. More info [here](https://github.com/hdinsight/spark-eventhubs/issues/80#issuecomment-300107709)